# Is there any way to make a call on iphone without using built-in dial application?

Tags: iphone

I have to make a calling application. I found a method to make a call on iPhone which is as follows:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL RLWithString:@"tel://8005551212"]];
My question is, this method calls iPhone built-in application.
I want to make direct call without using this built-in application. 
Are there other ways to make a call on iPhone programaticaly?
I just want to by pass the Dial Application.

Another question, is there any way to clear call history from iPhone. 
???? Please help me to solve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

No brotha. You cannot make call without calling the inbuilt iPhone Call application.

Theres no way possible to call directly So you have to bear that thing. But it calls directly means that you dont have to dial the number for it. It gets call automatically because the call client is installed in iPhone. So you have to use what it has given. Also trying to use any third party for calling may result in rejection of your application.

hAPPY cODING...